# IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank: Ranker training failure

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I'm following this [Tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/tutorial.shtml). I've successfully completed Stage 3. Now in stage 4, I downloaded the sample ground truth and tried to [create the ranker](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/?curl#create_ranker) using REST API. The ranker is created with status as training. When I try to get that ranker by its Id after some time, I receive following error:

```
{
  "ranker_id": "1eec74x28-rank-4116",
  "name": "First Training Data",
  "created": "2017-04-05T09:26:43.925Z",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/rankers/1eec74x28-rank-4116",
  "status": "Failed",
  "status_description": "Error encountered during training: Training data quality standards not met: invalid header (duplicate feature names). Row 1 of input data."
}
```

When I tried to identify the problem I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.shtml#manual) link. However, I'm unable to identify the issue here. I am not understanding the minimum standards of the training data.
Please guide me with corrective measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking here, a response to this question was posted on the IBM developer works forum: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/366976/watson-retrieve-and-rank-failing-to-train-the-rank.html